# Automapper. Многие к одному

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Здравствуйте!
Есть три источника данных (реляционная ДБ, EF 6, database first). Знаю, как привести к виду один к одному. Но не пойму, как положить все в одну модель (NewsModel), чтобы можно было ее одну передать во View, а не по кускам, как сейчас. Через запятую только один контекст вида db.News.ToList() судя по мануалам текущей версии automapper можно передать. Или где я ошибаюсь? Вот фрагмент кода из контроллера:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
News.Domain.PortalNewsEntities db = new Domain.PortalNewsEntities();
    var NewsResult = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<News.Domain.News>, 
          List<News.WebUI.Models.NewsModel>>(db.News.ToList());
    var CategoryResult = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<News.Domain.Category>,
            List<News.WebUI.Models.NewsModel>>(db.Category.ToList());
var TypeResult = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<News.Domain.Type>,
            List<News.WebUI.Models.NewsModel>>(db.Type.ToList());
    return View(NewsResult);
}
```

Профайл:

```
public class EntityToProfile: Profile
{
    public EntityToProfile()
    {          
       CreateMap<News.Domain.News, News.WebUI.Models.NewsModel>()
         .ForMember(d => d.idNews, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
         .ForMember(d => d.nameNews, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
         .ForMember(d => d.descriptionNews, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description));
        CreateMap<News.Domain.Category, News.WebUI.Models.NewsModel>()
         .ForMember(d => d.idCategory, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
         .ForMember(d => d.nameCategory, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
        // .ForMember(d => d.News, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.News))
        ;
        CreateMap<News.Domain.Type, News.WebUI.Models.NewsModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.idType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        .ForMember(d => d.nameType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
      //  .ForMember(d => d.Category, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category))
      ;
    }
}
```

Инициализация:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<EntityToProfile>();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Вот:

```
public partial class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.News = new HashSet<News>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
public partial class Type
{
    public Type()
    {
        this.Category = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }
}
```

Это все то, что сформировалось автоматически.
Вот модель, которая нужна:

```
public class NewsModel
{
    public int idNews { get; set; }
    public string nameNews { get; set; }
    public string descriptionNews { get; set; }       
    public int idCategory { get; set; }
    public string nameCategory { get; set; }
   //   public ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
    public int idType { get; set; }
    public string nameType { get; set; }
   //   public ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59795/discussion-on-question-by-stanislav1987-automapper---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как логично заключить - маппить многие к одному нельзя.

Исходя из дискуссии в комментариях стало ясным, что требуется скрещивать таблицы базы с помощью [`IQueryable.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534644(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var news = db.News
    .Join(db.Categories, n => n.CategoryId, c => c.Id, (n, c) => new {n, c})
    .Join(db.Types, nc => nc.c.TypeId, t => t.Id, (nc, t) => new { nc.n, nc.c, t })
    .Select(nct => new NewsModel
    {
        IdNews = nct.n.Id,
        NameNews = nct.n.Name,
        DescriptionNews = nct.n.Description,
        IdCategory = nct.c.Id,
        NameCategory = nct.c.Name,
        IdType = nct.t.Id,
        NameType = nct.t.Name
    }).ToList();
```

Так же тут можно было настроить маппинг с помощью Automapper, но я посчитал этот способ нецелесообразным, т.к. все равно пришлось бы явно прописывать маппинги.

Comment: cпасибо за ответ. Решение с автомаппером конечно никак не связано, но функцию свою вроде выполняет. Но теперь уже все равно надо разбираться, как это сделать с автомаппером, хотя бы ради интереса

Comment: @Stanislav1987 автомаппер нужен для авто маппинга (как ни странно **:)**). В данных же моделях ничего похожего нет, следовательно, и автомаппить нечего. Можно было бы конечно добавить еще одну модель с такими же полями как и в этом анонимном типе, настроить маппинг вручную (повторюсь - автомаппить тут нечего), но я считаю, что это нецелесообразно. Тем более в вашем тестовом задании использование излишков вряд ли будет вам плюсом, когда есть более тривиальное решение. Лучше просто упомяните на собесе, что вы знаете что это и работали с автомаппером :)

Comment: да это не собеседование) и вообще я не верно понял задание, вы были правы. Сегодня уже утром уточнил. Плоскую эту модель я не знаю может и вообще не реально через маппер собрать. Необходимо было просто спроецировать классы БД в новые классы, которые уже будут задействованы во вьюхе. Ну здесь сложного естественно ничего нет. Насчет целесообразности использования именно маппера не знаю. Но, в принципе, рабочий вариант и поддерживать изменения будет легко. Ну и все это нужно было, чтобы отделить слой БД от представления. Чтоб через новую модель работать с БД. Если понятно о чем я.

Comment: просто пока только учусь и даже в контроллере, который я привел, мне указали на ошибки. Сейчас их буду исправлять. Но в любом случае спасибо за ответ. Я его помечу, как верный.

Comment: @Stanislav1987 ошибки в контроллере? Разве что отсутствие архитектуры...

Comment: ну, во первых, ToList() не желательно использовать в больших проектах с большими БД, видимо, ef как то все это не оптимально вытягивает, надо разбираться. Ну и контекст. Каждый раз создается экземпляр класса в контроллере и лучше использовать что то типа ninject

Comment: Они про `.ToListAsync()` говорят как желательное? Или как они еще собираются тянуть данные из базы? Да и отсутствие архитектуры в принципе обуславливает отсутсвием Dependency Injection и использовании паттренов типа Repository и UnitOfWork

Comment: Архитектура там есть, это ведь мелкая часть глобально системы) To List() - возможно, имели в виду, то, что ef может построить не самый эффективный запрос к БД

Comment: @Stanislav1987 говоря про БД и EF, использование `.ToList()` (или лучше `.ToListAsync()`) - лучшее решение. Про какую архитектуру вы говорите? Прямо в контроллере работаете с базой, причем никакой другой логики нету в принципе...

Comment: ну главное, что основной вопрос был решен с автомаппером, все остальное второстепенно пока для меня. А как доберусь до этих вопросов и если будет не понятно обращусь за советом здесь) спасибо за оперативность